# How to catch an err in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, discord.js

How can I catch an error in node.js?

Here's my code:

```js
const { Client, Message, MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js")
const translate = require('@iamtraction/google-translate')
module.exports = {
  name: "ترجم",
  description: `يترجم اللغه فقط أستعمل !translate "الكلمه/الجمله يلي بدك تترجمها"`,
  aliases: ['translate'],
  run: async (client, message, args) => {
    const query = args.join(" ")
    const lang = args[0]
    if(!query) return message.reply('Please specify a text to translate');
    const translated = await translate(query, { to: lang });
    message.reply(translated.text);
  },
};
```

It works when I type in chat:

`!translate ar hello`

But when I type:

`!translate "not a real lang" hello`

It shutdowns with the error:

`Error: The language 'not a real lang' is not supported`

I tried `.catch`, I tried if and else, I tried `try`

Comment: "I tried .catch I tried if and else I tried "try" ..." << you forgot to show us how each try looked like and in what way it failed.

Comment: I meant: It's important to show these attempts and their errors so we can provider you better help by solving that problem you had in those tries.

Answer (score 2):

`async` functions return a value only if no error occurred. If something goes wrong an error is thrown that has to be caught.

You call the async function that errs with the `await` keyword, so you have to surround that with a `try { } catch (e) {}` block like this:

```js
try {
   const translated = await translate(query, { to: lang });
   message.reply(translated.text);
} catch (e) {
   message.reply('Translation failed: ' + e.message);
}
```

Since you take care of another possible error one line above, you could wrap the whole thing into a try-catch block and take care of all kinds of errors in a unified way:

```js
const { Client, Message, MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js")
const translate = require('@iamtraction/google-translate')
module.exports = {
  name: "ترجم",
  description: `يترجم اللغه فقط أستعمل !translate "الكلمه/الجمله يلي بدك تترجمها"`,
  aliases: ['translate'],
  run: async (client, message, args) => {
    try {
      const query = args.join(" ")
      const lang = args[0]
      if(!query) throw new Error('Please specify a text to translate');
      const translated = await translate(query, { to: lang });
      message.reply(translated.text);
    } catch (e) {
      if (message) {
        message.reply('Translation failed: ' + e.message);
      }
    }
  },
};
```

This way you will get a meaningful reply in any case (as long as you have a valid message). For example, maybe `args` is not an array.

Answer (score 0):

To catch errors in node.js you usually do this:

```js
try {
  // your code here
} catch (error){
  console.error(error);
  //your error response code here
}
```